# matplotlib can't be used from python3

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I have two python compilers on my Ubuntu 14.04 VM. I have installed `matplotlib` as

`pip install matplotlib`

But the matplotlib cannot be used from python3.It can be used from python2.7

If I use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` inside my script `test.py` and run it as

`python3 test.py`
I get the error

`ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'`

How can this be fixed.

Comment: Modules have to be installed separately for Python 2 and 3.  Installing a module for Python 2 doesn't install it for Python 3.

Comment: Why would you do that (installing with pip) instead of installing the package from your distro? Just curious...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pip3` to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install the package from your distro with:

`sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib`

It will probably throw an error when you import matplotlib, but it is solved by installing the package tkinter with:

`sudo apt-get install python3-tk`